# Transliteration API alternative to google API for Android

Tags: android, google-api, translate, indic

What are the other alternatives for doing transliteration ? since google transliteration api was deprecated previously. do suggest any services / api to perform translation.

Any indic language to English is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Microsoft](https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/1899a118-d202-492c-aa16-ba21c33c06cb) has a translation API for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I need to translate from telugu language to english,which is not supported by bing translator at this moment.